# Is it possible to use a state for ansible?

Tags: ansible, terraform

You might not understand what I am trying to say in the question. Before stating the problem, I would give an example to understand even more.

Let's take terraform for the example.

Imagine we use terraform to spin up an EC2 instance in the `aws`. So, we are currently storing the state locally. Let's say we need to add a `tag` to the `ec2` instance.

So what we do is, we add the this small block to achieve that.

```
tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
```

Nothing complex, just simple as it is. So, as we add a tag, the terraform will look for any changes in the state and as it found a tag has been added, it runs and **only add the tag** without recreating the whole instance. (There can be other scenarios where it needs to recreate the instance but let's leave those for now)

So, as I mentioned, `terraform` doesn't recreate the instance for adding a tag. If we want to add another tag, it will add the tag without recreating the instance. Just as simple as that.
doesn't matter how many times we run the `terraform apply` it doesn't do any changes to existing resources unless we made any in the terraform files.

So, let's now come to the real question.

Let's say we want to install a `httpd` using `ansible`. So I write ansible playbook. And it will use the `yum` package and install and then start and enable the service.

Okay it is simple like that.

Let's say we we run the same playbook for the second time, now will try to execute the same commands from scratch without checking first whether it has executed this playbook before?

I have couple of experiences where I try to install some services and when I try to execute the same playbook again, it fails.

Is it possible to preserve the state in `ansible` just like we do in `terraform` so it always **only execute the newer changes other than executing from the start on the second run**?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be describing [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence):

> Idempotence is the property of certain operations in mathematics and computer science whereby they can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application.

It's up to you to make sure your playbooks are idempotent in ansible. You could do this for your example using the [`package`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html) and [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) modules.

```yaml
- name: Setup Apache
  hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - name: Install Apache
      package:
        name: httpd
        state: present
    - name: Start and enable Apache
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: started
        enabled: yes
```

Ansible doesn't achieve idempotence by retaining state on the the controller. Each module should check the state of the host it's operating on to determine what changes it needs to make to achieve the state specified by the playbook. If it determines that it doesn't need to make any changes then that's what it should report back to the controller.

Comment: Okay understandable. But let's say we have a scenario where we can only execute that command once and if we execute this, it fails. (eg:- joining kubernetes worker nodes with master nodes). How to tackle such a situation with ansible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kubernetes but in that instance you could create a module which would first check whether the worker node is joined to the master and join it if is not already. Such a module may well already exist.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to create a module like that? How can I do this? Forget the worker node or kubernetes, assume creating a file using ansible is equivalent to a worker node joining the master node and can you tell me how to write the module and dhow the checking can be done?

Comment: Modules are written in python and execute code on the target host. You would use python's filesystem API to check whether the file exists and create it if not. For more details I suggest reading the [ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#creating-a-module).